# What do I do to properly import scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I downloaded scipy multiple times from pip and put it into the terminal to the point where it always tells me "condition satisfied". However I keep on getting the same error on VsCode where it tells me:

Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'scipy'

What do I do?

I tried downloading scipy by using pip multiple times, and it still doesn't work

Comment: Is the `pip` you're running using the same Python that VSCode is using?

Comment: Not sure, how do I verify that? Sorry, im kinda new to vscode so I'm not too good at it yet

Comment: Can you import it with a plain python terminal?  How about other modules like `numpy`?  As for VSCode, can you import other modules that you loaded with `pip`?   The challenge with helping you is we don't know whether there are several pythons, different paths, and other details of your setup.  And it's tricky to help you find out those details yourself.